# Python order list of lists of floats

Tags: python, list

So if I have this list `[['a', 0.1], ['b', 0.05], ['c', 1.5]]`. How does one order it by the second value so that the ordered list looks like this `[['b', 0.05], ['a', 0.1], ['c', 1.5]]`?

Answer (score 1):

```
from operator import itemgetter
list  = [['a', 0.1], ['b', 0.05], ['c', 1.5], ['d', 0.2]]
a = sorted(list, key=itemgetter(1))
print(list)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sorted` and tell it to use the second element:

```
a = [['a', 0.1], ['b', 0.05], ['c', 1.5]]
print(sorted(a, key=lambda k: k[1]))
```

`key=lambda k: k[1]` tells it take the second element (`k[1]`) and sort based on those values.